# Launch Screen Flow from Aura Component within a Modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, screen-flow

I created a screen flow that I would like to launch from than Aura component
The behavior should be the following:

1. One button
2. On click Open a Modal
3. Display the Screen flow content in the modal

if I put my lightning:flow aura:id outside the Modal then it works and I see my screen flow AND a button
if I put it outside my modal then I get an error

A Component Error has occured! Error: Action failed: c:getBookingsFromScreenFlow$controller$doInit [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startFlow')] Component: c:getBookingsFromScreenFlow . Caused by: Action failed: c:getBookingsFromScreenFlow$controller$doInit [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startFlow')]

I have no idea how I can make it work
Could you please help me ?
thx you

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <!--Boolean attribute to indicate if modal is open or not 
       default value is false as modal is closed when page is loaded 
    -->
    <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
        <lightning:button variant="brand"
                          label="What is Modal/PopUp Box?"
                          title="What is Modal/PopUp Box?"
                          onclick="{! c.openModel }" />
        <!--Use aura:if tag to display/hide popup based on isModalOpen value-->  
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">
             
            <!-- Modal/Popup Box starts here-->
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <!-- Modal/Popup Box Header Starts here-->
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                              onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                              alternativeText="close"
                                              variant="bare-inverse"
                                              class="slds-modal__close"/>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Add booking to opportunity</h2>
                    </header>
                    <!--Modal/Popup Box Body Starts here-->
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <lightning:flow aura:id="Screen_Flow_Add_multiple_Boookings_to_opportunity" />
                    </div>
                    <!--Modal/Popup Box Footer Starts here-->
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning:button variant="neutral"
                                          label="Cancel"
                                          title="Cancel"
                                          onclick="{! c.closeModel }"/>
                        <lightning:button variant="brand"
                                          label="OK"
                                          title="OK"
                                          onclick="{!c.submitDetails}"/>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controler:

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        
    },
    openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // Set isModalOpen attribute to true
      component.set("v.isModalOpen", true);
   },
  
   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // Set isModalOpen attribute to false  
      component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
   },
  
   submitDetails: function(component, event, helper) {
      // Set isModalOpen attribute to false
      //Add your code to call apex method or do some processing
      component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
   },
   doInit : function(component) {
       console.log('testouille')
      
       var flow = component.find('Screen_Flow_Add_multiple_Boookings_to_opportunity');
       var inputVariables = [
          {name: "varOppID", type: "String", value: component.get("v.recordId") }
       ];
       console.log('inputVariables', inputVariables);
       flow.startFlow('Screen_Flow_Add_multiple_Boookings_to_opportunity', inputVariables);    
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to start the Flow in the init handler, which is executed when the component initializes, when your isModalOpen value is set to `false`. Since you have the modal (and Flow) inside an `aura:if` tag that uses `isModalOpen`, the component.find() function in the initialization returns undefined (nothing inside an `aura:if` component is rendered until it is `true`).

You could solve this by running the logic that you have in `doInit` as part of `openModal` so that you initialize the Flow after the `lightning:flow` component exists.